# When did Hulk get so intelligent?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

As noted by Thor in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hulk was the "stupid Avenger" and as we all know he really wasn't that smart in all the movies he was in - up until *Thor: Ragnarok* where he suddenly seems to be speaking in semi-intelligent sentences. My question is, how and when did Hulk get so smart?

Comment: He was always able to talk, just not when he was enraged. In he first Avengers movie he called Loki "Puni God" after fighting with Loki. I think he has some intelligence, but when he is enraged he is like a wild beastl.

Comment: @JoeryJV: This makes sense from Banner's perspective. Initially, he hated the Hulk and tried to hide him. Hulk only came out when Banner was _so_ angry that he could not control himself (= Hulk is so angry that he acts like a beast). But at the end of The Avengers, Banner learns to not hide the Hulk, thus allowing him to come out at times where Banner is less-than-uncontrollably angry, thus allowing for Hulk to exist at time where he is not necessarily enraged. "Puny God" is the first occurence of Hulk speaking (iirc), and also the first occurence of Banner allowing (and trusting in) Hulk.

Comment: @Flater The first instance of Banner allowing the Hulk is in the 2008 film, when he transforms to stop Abomination, and at the end transforms in a controlled manner.

Comment: @GreySage As far as I'm aware, Norton-Hulk is a different storyline from Ruffalo-Hulk. In The Avengers, Ruffalo-Hulk hasn't learned to control (nor trust) the Hulk yet.

Comment: @Flater Both Norton and Ruffalo are both in the MCU. It was only an actor change. Banner has been consistent.

Comment: It's a continuity error. *runs* *ducks*

Comment: @krillgar Then it seems equally erroneous for Norton-Hulk to be able to transform in a _controlled_ manner (as per GreySage's comment), yet Ruffalo-Hulk is initially not even open to the idea of _controlling_ Hulk and instead tries to ignore his existence. They may both be in the MCU but there is no continuity between the two Hulks whatsoever.

Comment: @Flater That's something that Banner always worries about, even in the comics: Who is he going to hurt when he loses control? Even if he can control it most of the time, there are still instances (like the first transformation on the Helicarrier in Avengers) where something happens to him and he's unable to control his transformation.

Comment: @krillgar: Ruffalo-Banner initially refused to voluntarily use his Hulk _to save the world from invaders_. That showcases a considerably larger apprehension about the Hulk's usefulness compared to where Norton-Banner left it, thus suggesting a lack of continuity and no real connection between the two Hulks.

Comment: @Flater bad, inconsistent writing aside, they are explicitly the same hulk and take place in the same universe. Tony Stark even comes to Norton at the end of the 2008 movie to talk about the Avengers.

Comment: @GreySage Stark talks to General Ross in the post-credit scene, not Banner.

Comment: @Flater Norton had a 1 second scene at the very end of the movie. In the intervening time, Banner traveled the world. Who's to say there wasn't some other event where he thought he was in control of Hulk before Natasha found him?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### According to director Taika Waititi, just in time for filming<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>And by that I obviously mean, while on Sakaar.

In an interview with CBR, Taika Waititi revealed that Hulk's time on Sakaar allowed him to become more comfortable in his green skin and learn about himself:

> Yeah, that was really, just like with Chris, just wanting make it more interesting for Mark to play that character, because in the films he just said one or two words and just destroyed everything, and that was the version of Hulk I think that everybody knows.
>
> But this version -- the smarter version -- it's just become so much more interesting and engaging, because he's been the Hulk for two years. He's a hero on this planet and he's had more time to just sit with himself and feel comfortable in his own skin.
> <sub>[Thor: Ragnarok’s Smarter Hulk Is ‘Comfortable in His Own Skin’](https://www.cbr.com/thor-ragnarok-smarter-hulk-explained/)</sub>

On the same note, some of the features of Hulk's new "bachelor pad", namely the hot tub, aren't simply for him to splash about in, but used by Hulk to have moments of introspection.

> Now you can see Hulk sitting still and being kind of like a big silverback. There’s there’s this moment when he’s in the hot tub in his apartment – he just feels like General [Colonel] Kurtz in Apocalypse Now. He’s just sitting there, just contemplating things and you can feel him probably ruminating over all sorts of stuff inside his head. And that introspective, that very still version of Hulk, I think is way more fascinating than the guy that just destroys everything.
> <sub>[ibid.](https://www.cbr.com/thor-ragnarok-smarter-hulk-explained/)</sub>

Comment: `because he's been the Hulk for two years` Don't forget, that's two _Earth_ years (or years according to Thor), so who knows how long he's been on Sakaar.

Comment: @Möoz Two years, it says it right there in the quote.

Comment: @Edlothiad The quote does not make any mention of whether they are earth years or years of local time, which might be different. Therefore, the statement holds.

Comment: @Cronax the film states it's been two Earth years, and _supposedly_ far more on Sakaar. Given the quote say two years, one can assume the supposition from the film to have been an exaggeration.

Comment: @Edlothiad You seem to be disregarding the possibility that time might pass differently on Sakaar. Just because on Earth, it feels like two years have passed, doesn't mean that it can't feel like more time has passed if you spend it elsewhere.

Comment: @Cronax I'm not disregarding the possibility. I'm disregarding that it's _certainty_ I support the possibility, but am sceptical of it. On Earth it doesn't "feel like" two years have passed, two years _have_ passed. It doesn't matter how long it feels like he's been in the Hulk, he's been the Hulk for two years, and that's what it is. In this case the word of the Director is final, if you have issues with it, take it up with him, not me.

Comment: At 40 minutes into the movie, Loki mentions arriving at the planet "weeks ago" when they both left the bifrost only moments apart.  This could be explained by assuming that that was still enough for them to be in vastly different areas of space, except for that the grandmaster specifically says "time works differently here on sakkar."  Though there is always the chance he is lying.